# Sending Email with C# + Exchange 2007 and possible MS-SQL Que

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, exchange-server

I hate to rehash this as it gets beat to death, however after digging through questions for the past hour and not finding much of a definitive answer here we go:

Requirements:

Send batches of 1,ooo to 1o,ooo emails to varying sets of email recipients from an C# ASP application using a 2007 exchange server several times a day.

Concerns:

1) Given the requirements (which I think are not too extreme) what is the "best" way to go about this ?

2) Can I send say 1o,ooo emails at once or should they be sent in batches of a hundred ?

3) I see the mention of database Que's in other threads regarding this topic, how is this done ?  Is there a way to point exchange to a separate Que. or does a separate service have to run against the the table.  That being said are there any open source projects to handle this type of thing ?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer as it has nothing to do with your technical requirements, but sending out that many emails per day from a personal (or even an ordinary corporate) mail server is likely to get your server blacklisted. Is there a reason that you can't use an ordinary bulk mailing service? They already have measures in place to comply with things like CAN-SPAM and provide you with an API to do what you need to do.

Comment: @Adam Robinson Well currently the office is sending out the same volume of email accept they manually export the list from our app to excel and dump it into outlook and send it in batches of 500, hence my thoughts n batches ?  And this has been going on for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use my service bus for this: http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

I have an EMail.Server endpoint that SendEMailCommand messages are sent to.  It also handles attachments.

The service bus uses a queue to store the messages and the endpoint implementation uses SMTP to send the e-mails.

It is a rather simple infrastructure endpoint and I am quite happy to mail you the code should you be interested.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you would share the code with me david[at]nyc-software.com